# How to mock an instance created in React JS component?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to mock an instance which is created in a React JS component.
The instance is a common ECMAScript 2016 class, not a React component. I use Jasmine, React JS TestUtils and babel-rewire for testing.

My React component code looks like this:

```
import MyHandler from '../../js/MyHandler';
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.myHandler = new MyHandler();
    }

    someComponentMethod() {
      this.myHandler.someMethod();
    }

    render() {
      return <div>...</div>;
    }
}
```

My class looks like this:

```
export default class MyHandler {

   someMethod() {
       // ...
   }
}
```

My test and what I tried so far:

```
// gives exception
let myHandler = new MyHandler();
let spy = spyOn(myHandler, "someMethod").and.returnValue(null);
MyComponent.__Rewire__ ("MyHandler", spy);
// also gives exeption
MyComponent.__set__ ("MyHandler", spy);

let component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent />);
```

For mocking other React components I use `babel-rewire` which works great. But I can't replace the instance by a mock or spy.

I know I could pass the instace into the component as a property (and thus mock it in a test), but I wonder if this is good practise and I'm afraid I'll have the problem in the next coomponent .

Any help appreciated!

Comment: your instance is being imported right?

Comment: Yes it it, missed that in the snippet. It's imported via `import MyHandlerHandler from '../../js/MyHandler';`

Comment: take a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/inject-loader i use it all the time to test my components

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you have a small example how the import looks like with the inject loader? Does it work with babel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the injector loader something along these lines

```
const MyComponentInjector = require('inject!'MyComponent');
MyComponent = MyComponentInjector({
  '../../js/MyHandler': YourMockedClass
}).default
```

that would provide a MyComponent with YourMockedClass as Mock for your handler

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I changed your sample to `import inject from 'inject!../js/MyComponent'` and it works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: ahh forgot to add .default to the code. when using required anything that is by default exported is under the .default property. can you paste the complete code to see how you sued it using system.js imports?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, here is the complete code:

```
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import React from 'react';
import inject from 'inject!../js/MyComponent';

it("mocks the call", () => {

        class mockClass {
            constructor() {
                console.log("some constructor fake");
            }

            someMethod() {
                console.log("some method fake");
            }
        }

        let mock = new mockClass();


        let MyComponent = inject({
            '../../js/MyHandler': mockClass
        }).default;


        let component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent />);
        component.someComponentMethod();
    });
```